# Does Cloud Spanner offer a NUMERIC type

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-spanner

I have an application that stores monetary amounts. I want to store this in Cloud Spanner. Using a `FLOAT64` is dangerous because of [well-known problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730019/why-not-use-double-or-float-to-represent-currency) with floating point accuracy.

Other databases offer a `NUMERIC` type for just this kind of use-case. What should I do in Cloud Spanner?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cloud Spanner now supports NUMERIC data type with 38 decimal digits of precision, including 9 after decimal points.
Please refer to the documentation [here](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/data-types#numeric_type).

Answer (score 2):

Cloud Spanner does not offer a `NUMERIC` type or a `DECIMAL` type.

One workaround is to store your quantities in an `INT64` column, and store them in the finest-granularity unit with which you will ever work. For example, if you are dealing with US Dollars, you could store the quantities in cents ($0.01). So $7.13 would be presented as 713 cents in your column. For some applications, you might want even finer granularity (e.g. micro-dollars) in order to minimize rounding issues.

There are other workarounds possible. For example, you could somehow serialize your numeric values to a string and store these in a `STRING` or `BYTES` column. Naively, just storing `"7.13"` could work, but there are of course more complex representations possible (e.g. a JSON object like `"{'dollars': 7, 'cents': 13'}"`).